# I haven't been truly hungry in a few years

Tags: diet

I am starting to get a little concerned about something.  I haven't felt truly hungry in a few years.  I just eat because after a day or two of not eating I feel like the nutrients are necessary for my body, but it's not because I'm hungry.

Just a little background I am in my early-mid 20's and 20-25 pounds overweight depending on the day.

I have looked into this a little and a lot of the cases I have found are usually associated with going through a recent event that causes severe sadness or even depression.  However, I haven't really felt sad or depressed, so unless I am experiencing a more subtle form of depression/sadness I am guessing my problem is dietary.

In terms of what it feels like: it's like I always have a partially digested meal in my body even after a few days or not eating.  I am by no means well educated in this field, but the only two things I could think of are that either my metabolism is extremely slow, or that there is just something "clogging" my system.

I am just looking for some possible explanations and solutions to what might be causing this.

Comment: Personal medical questions are [considered off topic](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here), and there are too many considerations to likely get a good answer here.  A simple abdominal exam could reveal a lot, so I recommend going to your primary care provider or a clinic.